# How to lock Google Cloud Storage text file to have transaction like operation

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have a text file (say, "X") stored on GCS and created and updated by GCS Client Library. I use GAE Python. On every addition of some data by user of my website, I add a Task (taskqueue.Task) to the "default" queue to do some actions including modification of file ("X").

Sometimes, I get the following error in the logs:

```
E 2014-07-20 03:19:06.238 500 3KB 430ms /t
0.1.0.2 - - [19/Jul/2014:14:49:06 -0700] "POST /t HTTP/1.1" 500 2569 "http://www.myappdomain.com/p" "AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)" "www.myappdomain.com" ms=430 cpu_ms=498 cpm_usd=0.000287 queue_name=default task_name=14629523467445182169 instance=00c61b117c48b4db44a58e0d454310843e7848 app_engine_release=1.9.7 trace_id=3db3eb580b76133e90947539c0446910  
   I 03:19:05.813 [class TaskQueueWorker]  work=[sitemap_index_entry]  
   I 03:19:05.813 country_id=[US] country_name=[USA] state_id=[CA] state_name=[California] city_id=[SVL] city_name=[Sunnyvale]  
   I 03:19:05.836 locality_id_old=[-1] locality_id_new=[28]  
   I 03:19:05.879 locality_name_old=[] locality_name_new=[XYZ]  
   I 03:19:05.879 command=[ADD]  
   E 03:19:06.207 File on GCS has changed while reading.  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)  
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)  
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)  
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()  
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)  
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)  
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myappdomain/1.377368272328585247/main_v3.py", line 15259, in post
    gcs_file = gcs.open (index_filename, mode='r')  
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myappdomain/1.377368272328585247/cloudstorage/cloudstorage_api.py", line 94, in open
    buffer_size=read_buffer_size)  
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myappdomain/1.377368272328585247/cloudstorage/storage_api.py", line 220, in __init__
    check_response_closure()  
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myappdomain/1.377368272328585247/cloudstorage/storage_api.py", line 448, in _checker
    self._check_etag(resp_headers.get('etag'))  
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~myappdomain/1.377368272328585247/cloudstorage/storage_api.py", line 476, in _check_etag
    raise ValueError('File on GCS has changed while reading.')  
ValueError: File on GCS has changed while reading.  
   I 03:19:06.235 Saved; key: __appstats__:045800, part: 144 bytes, full: 74513 bytes, overhead: 0.002 + 0.004; link: http://www.myappdomain.com/_ah/stats/details?time=1405806545812
```

I suspect that multiple triggered tasks try to open and update the file ("X") at the same time. And that causes the above exception.  Please suggest a way to lock access to that file so that only one task is able to modify it at a time(similar to a transaction).

Appreciate your help and guidance.

**UPDATE**
Another way to prevent the above problem could be to modify one of the following queue.yaml parameter for the queue:

> bucket_size

OR

> max_concurrent_requests

But, not sure which one to modify.

Comment: what about creating a task queue that can only execute 1 task at a time and executing all such tasks from that queue?

Comment: @PaulCollingwood +1 and Thanks for your reply. Coincidentally, I too just thought on similar lines and had updated the question (at the same time as your comment arrived). I have doubt about which parameter to change. I have updated my question. Could you please help?

Comment: I'd start with max_concurrent_requests = 1

Comment: @PaulCollingwood Thanks. Would try that out. You can provide the above comments as SO "answer" so that I can accept it.

Comment: sure, but don't accept until you've tested the solution as there might be a better answer out there :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A task queue of max_concurrent_requests = 1 should ensure that only one edit is made at a time to a file.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/queue#Python_Defining_push_queues_and_processing_rates

> If you want to prevent too many tasks from running at once or to
>   prevent datastore contention, you use max_concurrent_requests.
>
> **max_concurrent_requests (push queues only)**
>   Sets the maximum number of tasks that can be executed at any given
>   time in the specified queue. The value is an integer. By default, this
>   directive is unset and there is no limit on the maximum number of
>   concurrent tasks. One use of this directive is to prevent too many
>   tasks from running at once or to prevent datastore contention.
>
> Restricting the maximum number of concurrent tasks gives you more
>   control over your queue's rate of execution. For example, you can
>   constrain the number of instances that are running the queue's tasks.
>   Limiting the number of concurrent requests in a given queue allows you
>   to make resources available for other queues or online processing.

Of course, you should build in logic that'll allow failed tasks to re-try etc, or you may end up with worse problems then you have now.

Comment: Setting it solved the exception problem. But, still I am not sure what is the difference between setting `rate` and `max_concurrent_requests`. 
Thanks :)

Comment: `Rate` is more like how many jobs you can perform in a set amount of time. So like `5/s` (I think more accurately it's the rate for many tasks can get leased from a bucket). If you have a quick task (as well as a large enough `bucket-size`) certainly a low rate can have multiple requests going at once. The `max_concurrent_requests` enforces exactly how many tasks can run at a given time. They work together, but `max_concurrent_requests` is more directly controlling your queue.

Comment: Think of `Rate` as how many tasks that can be kicked off per time segment (e.g. 5/s = 5 new tasks started per second).  The `max_concurrent_requests` is how many of these tasks that can be running at the same time.  If `max_concurrent_requests` is met, the taskqueue will not kick off anymore tasks.  This is good for throttling the number of concurrennt calls to an API, for example.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to rely on GCS itself using [preconditions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/generations-preconditions#_Preconditions)

This allows updating a file only. See the docs:

> Preconditions are often used in mutating requests — uploads, deletes, copies, or metadata updates — to prevent race conditions. Race conditions can arise when the same request is sent repeatedly or when independent processes interfere with each other. For example, multiple request retries after a network interruption, or users performing a read-modify-write operation on the same object can create race conditions.